# SKShapeNode - CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect is causing a 'Potential Leak of an object' warning

Tags: memory-leaks, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have an SKShapeNode and I am setting the shape as a RoundedRectangle but when I analyze the code I am receiving a warning that states there is a potential leak of an object.

My interfaceFile is as follows:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface letterSpace : SKShapeNode

-(instancetype) initWithCharacter:(NSString *)character xPosition:(float)x yPosition:(float)y device:(NSString *)device;
    @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL occupied;
    @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL whiteSpace;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *character;
    @property (atomic) float secondLineX;
    @property (atomic) float secondLineY;


@end
```

And then the implementation is

```
 #import "letterSpace.h"

@implementation letterSpace
-(instancetype) initWithCharacter:(NSString *)character xPosition:(float)x yPosition:(float)y device:(NSString *)device{
    self = [super init];
        if(self){

            if ([device isEqualToString:@"IPHONE"]) {
                [self setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 2), 1, 1, nil)]; // Potential Leak of an object on this line
                _secondLineX = 36*8;
                _secondLineY = -36;
            }else{
                [self setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 3.5), 1, 1, nil)]; // Potential Leak of an object on this line
                _secondLineX = 575;
                _secondLineY = -71;
            }
            self.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            if ([character  isEqual: @" "]) {
               self.occupied = TRUE;
               self.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor];
               self.character = character;
               self.whiteSpace = TRUE;
            }else{
                self.whiteSpace = FALSE;
                self.occupied = FALSE;
                self.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:80.0f/255.0f
                                                green:227.0f/255.0f
                                                                 blue:194.0f/255.0f
                                                                alpha:1];
            }
            if (y <8) {
                self.position = CGPointMake(x, 0);
            }
            else{
                self.position = CGPointMake(x - _secondLineX, _secondLineY);
            }


            self.name = character;
        }
        return self;
    }

@end
```

Any ideas how to solve this leak? or what's causing it?

Comment: Your leak is probably in the way you use your custom class rather than the class code itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Core Foundation objects, you own an object if you call function that*:

- have “Create” embedded in the name;
- have "Copy" embedded in the name;

*however, this does not apply to a methods that return Objective-C objects.

If you are an owner of an object, you must relinquish ownership when you have finished using it using `CFRelease` (or the corresponding type-specific variants).

In ARC environment, the compiler does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core Foundation objects. You must call `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` (or the corresponding type-specific variants)

Also you need to tell the compiler about the ownership of the object if you cast between Objective-C and Core Foundation objects:

- `__bridge` transfers a pointer between Objective-C and Core Foundation with no transfer of ownership;
- `__bridge_retained` or `CFBridgingRetain` casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also transfers ownership to you. You are responsible for calling `CFRelease` or a related function to relinquish ownership of the object;
- `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC. ARC is responsible for relinquishing ownership of the object.

So, in your case:

`path` has a type of `CGPathRef`, which from a Core Graphics frameworks that adopts to Core Foundation memory management conventions. So, we apply the rule "If you call the method that have a "Create" embedded in the name - you own it". It is not matter whether it is Manual (in manual you must) or Automatic (ARC environment does not automatically manage the lifetimes of Core Foundation objects) Memory Management you must release this object.

```
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 2), 1, 1, nil);
[self setPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);
```

**or** you can use Cocoa analogue `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:(NSRect)rect xRadius:(CGFloat)xRadius yRadius:(CGFloat)yRadius`.

Also, I would recommend you to use `NULL` instead of `nil` in `CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect`.

- [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i)
- [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i)
- [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)